# Find Invalid User Relationships in User to Manager Map (validate map as valid tree structure with no circular relationships)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, validation, groovy

We have a new service where an admin can upload a spreadsheet of new users they want to add to our application. During our processing we make a union map of all the users both existing and new additions, and check to make sure that the users will still be in a valid tree structure(s) after the update goes through.

**Requirements:**
For the user relationship tree structure to be valid,

- There can be no circular references (ex. Users cannot be each other's manager)
- A single branch of the tree cannot exceed 50 users (ex. There should not be 50 middle-management managers between CEO and Janitor).
- Its ok if the tree is severed into multiple trees when a user does not have a manager. Separate warnings are generated for that circumstance.

This may need to scale to up to 1,000,000 user relationships, so far, the current solution supports at least 10,000 user relationships in a reasonable amount of time (less than 1 minute running locally).

FYI this is Groovy/Java

**Solution So Far:**
I have a method that takes a HashMap of user relationships and it returns a list of invalid users ids.

```
Map<String, String> userRelationships = [["userId1": "userId2"], ["userId2": "userId3"], ...]
def invalidRelationships = findInvalidRelationships(userRelationships)
```

.

```
/**
 * Takes a map of user relationships (user with corresponding manager)
 * For each relationship, climb up the tree and look to see if the user is repeated in their branch
 * If user is found again up the tree branch, that is a bad circular reference
 * If the current branch goes on past 50 users, that is too long and also invalid
 * Report all users that are part of that bad relationship
 * userRelationship.key is the user
 * userRelationship.value is the manager
 */
def findInvalidUserRelationships(Map<String, String> userRelationships) {
    Set<String> invalidUserRelationshipUsers = []
    userRelationships.each { Entry<String, String> currentUserRelationship ->
        Set<String> usersInCurrentBranch = []
        Entry<String, String> nextIterationRelationship = currentUserRelationship
        while (
                nextIterationRelationship?.value && //while not top of tree (not null manager)
                        !invalidUserRelationshipUsers.contains(nextIterationRelationship.key) && //while user not part of circular relationship
                        !usersInCurrentBranch.contains(nextIterationRelationship.key) //while user not connected to other circular relationship
        ) {
            usersInCurrentBranch << nextIterationRelationship.key
            //if bad circular relationship found or branch has more than max users, report users as invalid
            if (nextIterationRelationship.value == currentUserRelationship.key || usersInCurrentBranch?.size() > 50) {
                invalidUserRelationshipUsers += usersInCurrentBranch
            }
            //set next user relationship to check in next iteration (manager's manager) - (go upline)
            nextIterationRelationship = new MapEntry(
                    nextIterationRelationship.value, //manager of current iteration user will be next user
                    userRelationships[nextIterationRelationship.value as String] //manager's manager
            )
        }
    }
    return invalidUserRelationshipUsers as List<String>
}
```

I have already made lots of optimizations, at least compared to how bad it was before using only Lists instead of Maps and Sets, but I was wondering if there would be a more efficient solution to this problem. I wondered if a Java TreeMap would be appropriate somewhere here, but could not figure out how it could improve performance.

Comment: Great first question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using TreeMap?

You have a tree represented in a `HashMap`, which is completely fine. A `TreeMap` has a specific tree structure based on `comparable`. I don't think the hierarchy of the employees can be expressed with a suitable `comparable`.

### Variable names

Meaningful variable names are good. In this case, the operation of `findInvalidUserRelationships` is purely mathematical (finding cycles in a graph, checking whether the height of a tree exceeds 50) and I find it easier to understand the method using more math related names. It might also be more readable here to use

```
map.each { k, v -> println("key: $k, value: $v") }
```

instead of

```
map.each { entry -> println("key: $entry.key, value: $entry.value") }
```

So I have rewritten your method and in the following I will refer to the rewritten version.

```
List<String> findInvalidNodes(Map<String, String> edges) {
    Set<String> invalidNodes = []
    edges.each { String currentNode, _ ->
        Set<String> nodes = []
        String child = currentNode
        String parent = edges[currentNode]

        while ( parent && !invalidNodes.contains(child) && !nodes.contains(child) ) {
            nodes << child
            if (parent == currentNode || nodes.size() > 50) {
                invalidNodes.addAll(nodes)
            }
            child =  parent
            parent = edges[parent]
        }
    }
    return invalidNodes as List<String>
}
```

I have already conducted a minor change by replacing `invalidNodes += nodes` with `invalidNodes.addAll(nodes)`. This can be a slight improvement of performance since `invalidNodes` grows over time and `+=` creates a new list each time it is invoked while `addAll` simply adds items to the existing list.

### Performance

You traverse the tree starting from each node to the top. Therefore there are several nodes that are visited multiple times. Think about a linear tree structure.

```
Map edges = (1..51).collectEntries { [it+1 as String, it as String] }
findInvalidNodes(edges)
```

The tree has 52 nodes and is therefore invalid. But since I built the map `edges` so that the order of entries is worst case, you start with nodes `1, 2, ..., 51` and need `1+2+3+...+51 = 1326` loops to detect that the nodes are invalid. If you started with the last entry of the map it would only take `51` loops.
Since the height is limited to a constant amount I would see the method still as scalable. You can think about saving information for visited nodes and use that information once you find a visited node.

### Is the Method working as intended?

#### Root node missing

Due to the while condition `while(parent)` a child with no parent (therefore all roots of the trees) cannot be treated as invalid. For the same reason a root node will never show up in `nodes` list so effectively you check for tree height `> 51` and not tree height `> 50`.

#### Child of invalid Parent not invalid

Due to the while condition `while ( !invalidNodes.contains(child) )` the loop breaks once the parent of a child is invalid. But the child is never added to the `invalidNodes` list. Is this really intended?

```
Map edges = (1..101).collectEntries { [it+1 as String, it as String] }}
assert findInvalidNodes(edges) == [2, 3, ..., 52]
```

This tree has 102 nodes, but only `[2, 3, ..., 52]` are invalid. `53, 54, ..., 102` are not treated as invalid. If you add one more

```
Map edges = (1..102).collectEntries { [it+1 as String, it as String] }}
findInvalidNodes(edges)
assert findInvalidNodes(edges) == [2, 3, ..., 103]
```

all nodes are recognized as invalid.

This also implies that the order of the entries in `edges` affects which nodes appear in the `invalidNodes` list:

```
Map<String, String> edges = [:]
edges["53"] = "51"
edges.putAll( (1..51).collectEntries { [it+1 as String, it as String] } )
assert findInvalidNodes(edges) == [2, 3, ..., 50, 51, 53]
```

```
Map<String, String> edges = [:]
edges.putAll( (1..51).collectEntries { [it+1 as String, it as String] } )
edges["53"] = "51"
assert findInvalidNodes(edges) == [2, 3, ..., 50, 51, 52]
```

### Final words

Having said all this, for me as a non graph theory expert the task you are conducting - despite sounding so easy - is far from being trivial. So I would probably wind up with a lot of bugs in my code. But if I had to, I would rebuild the tree in a custom tree structure so that I can traverse the tree starting from the root. That is very flexible, but has great overhead compared to a simple HashMap.

**EDIT**

I thought it would only be fair to give a solution (that might contain bugs). This uses a HashMap as a tree representation, but with parent as key and a list of children as value. I wasn't sure if you really wanted a height limit of 51 or just 50 so this should be adjusted to your requirements.

```
List findInvalidNodesUsingMap(Map edges) {
    /*
    convert tree representation
    from child -> parent
    to parent -> children
    */
    Map tree = edges.groupBy { child, parent -> parent }
            .collectEntries { parent, Map children -> [parent, children.keySet()] }

    // nodes without parents must be roots
    Set roots = edges.values().findAll { !(it in edges.keySet()) }

    /*
    since all nodes can have at most one parent,
    all paths with cycles cannot have a root node.
    therefore, all nodes that cannot be accessed starting
    from one of the root nodes must be part of a path
    containing a cycle
    */

    Set validRoots = roots.findAll { heightBelowLimit(it, 1, tree) }

    Set validNodes = []
    validRoots.each { collectNodes(it, tree, validNodes) }

    Set invalidNodes = (roots + edges.keySet()).findAll { !(it in validNodes) }
    return invalidNodes as List
}

Boolean heightBelowLimit(String node, int level, Map tree){
    if(level > 50){
        false
    }else {
        !tree.containsKey(node)
                ? true
                : tree[node].every { heightBelowLimit(it, level + 1, tree) }
    }
}

void collectNodes(String node, Map tree, Set nodes){
    nodes << node
    if(tree.containsKey(node)){
        tree[node].each { collectNodes(it, tree, nodes) }
    }
}
```